# Automate Hyper-V post-snapshot merge and machine start

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

Here's a scenario that occurs quite frequently.

Before installing system updates I create a snapshot of a virtual machine in case something goes wrong. After the update is done and there are no problems, I want to remove the snapshot, as it would just be taking up space otherwise.

This means I need to turn the machine off (either completely, or save it). No issues there.

My gripe is that after saving the machine, I need to wait for the merge to complete (and depending on how many updates there were, this can take some time) and then manually bring the machine back up. I know Windows Server 2012 can perform merges when a machine is running, but we're using Windows Server 2008 R2.

Is there any way to have Hyper-V automate this process? I mean - bring the virtual machine up after merging, so I don't need to sit and wait around?

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is. Using PowerShell you can stop the vm, start the merge, wait for it to compete, then start the vm.

---

Update: I thought that running a merge was asynchronous when run from PowerShell, but it appears to be synchronous. So a script would look like this:

```
$vm = Get-VM theNameOfYourVm
$vm | Shutdown-VM
$vm | Get-VMCheckpoint | Merge-VMCheckpoint
$vm | Start-VM
```

Comment: Any chance you have such a script lying around? The "wait for it [merge] to complete" sounds like the biggest hurdle...

Comment: `Get-VMCheckpoint` is part of Windows Server 2012 HyperV commands, and isn't available on 2008 R2. `Get-VM` is also part of that (albeit an implementation can be downloaded from http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/

Needless to say, the script isn't needed on Windows 2012 (as merging can be performed on running machines), and just plainly won't work on 2008 R2.

Comment: PowerShell is available in SCVMM.

Comment: Ouch. :/ We don't have SCVMM. :< So... I take it without SCVMM or Server 2012 this isn't possible?